# suggestion for optimization problem with $\ell_{2,1}$ norm and Frobenius norm

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

Suppose I derive my application problem as the following type of optimization problem:
$$\min_X ||X||_{2,1}+||X^\top||_{2,1}+||X-A||_F,$$ where $X$ is a (square) matrix, $A$ is a constant matrix.

I am wondering is there any current optimization algorithm can solve this optimization problem (better with some convergence or theoretical guarantee)?

Comment: Can you define in the question what the $\|\cdot\|_{2,1}$ notation represents?

Comment: It is the [$\ell_{2,1}$ matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2,1_and_Lp,q_norms). It is just the $\ell_2$ norm of each column vector, and then sum them up. $||X||_F$ is just the $\ell_2$ norm of matrix $X$ viewed as a long vector ($vec(X)$).

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to take the square of the norm?

Comment: Being an unconstrained minimization, I would try Coordinate descent. The updates in the algorithm in your case will have a very simple expression w.r.t each variable.  As far as theoretical guarantees go, it is a first order method.

Comment: @NicholasMancuso I think the Frobenius norm is already square root of the sum of squares, and the $2$ in $\ell_{2,1}$ is also the square root.

Comment: @csTheoryBeginner Thanks! I will try coordinate descent.

Comment: @breezeintopl, it is just slightly more common (and easier!) to optimize for the squared norm